# Changing a Date field to current time

Tags: 7, datetime

How do I programmatically change the value of [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date)'s datetime field attached to an entity in Drupal 7, to the sites current time and timezone.

For example:

```
$entity = entity_load('node', 99);
// modify entity date
$entity->field_date_example = ...
entity_save($entity)
```

Comment: Change it when being saved or viewed? Change it every time the entity is viewed or just sometimes?

Comment: It shouldn't matter when it happens. More info added ^^